# Deploying docker using azure powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, azure-powershell

I am following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=in-process%2Cpowershell%2Cazure-powershell&pivots=programming-language-python) for creating azure function using custom image:

Everything works fine locally but the last stage does not work:
When I try to create the new function using the image :

```
New-AzFunctionApp -Name XXX -ResourceGroupName XXX -PlanName MyPremiumPlan -StorageAccount XXX -DockerImageName XXX/XXX:v1.6.0
```

I get the following error:

GetShareName : Cannot convert value "a" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

```
At C:\Users\<USER>\OneDrive\<FOLDER>\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Az.Functions\3.1.0\custom\New-AzFunctionApp.ps1:419 char:26
+             $shareName = GetShareName -FunctionAppName $Name
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [GetShareName], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger,GetShareNa
```

me

the name is just letters no numbers or any special chars.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Amit

Comment: Hi Amit Raz, Could you please refer to this [GitHub link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/13379)

Answer (score 0):

We have tested in our local environment, we are able to create the function app using cmdlet "New-Azfunctionapp" in PowerShell core version 7.1.3  but the same cmdlet in PowerShell version 5.1 is getting failed as shown in below

[image]

Looks like this an open issue to create a function app using PowerShell version 5.1 is getting failed with above error that you have shared.
Here is the [git hub link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/15430) where this issue is getting addressed.